# LiPo switch over PMOS

Tags: lipo

I try to design a circuit, where a LiPo is switched by a PMOS over a mechanical switch. Further, the USB Voltage can also occur and the LiPo should be decoupled. My first attempt looks like this, and it seems to work:

[image]

Now, the diode D2 is bad practise, because of the power dissipation, but I don't know how to get rid of it, since the Body Diode of M1 will directly couple the USB voltage into the battery. Has anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would use back-to-back P channel MOSFETs. The two body diodes will be opposite so they will never conduct, and you get the benefit of the Low on-resistance of the MOSFET.
See this electronics stackexchange answer for details: [Switch 5V with back voltage protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/switch-5v-with-back-voltage-protection)

Comment: This looks good on a first sight, but there comes a problem when the switch is on and VUSB is applied. The PMOS will directly conduct the current through into the battery, which will be overloaded. I'm currently looking for a feedback path, to constantly turn off the FETs when VUSB is applied, but cannot find any at the moment...